# removing tweets related to marketing

Tags: twitter, sentiment-analysis

I am working on tweet sentiment analysis (detecting users' view about plastic surgery treatments), but when I tried to extract the tweets, among the tweets that show the users' view there were also some tweets that are about the marketing of the treatment like I search Liposuction, then there were alot of the tweets that are not showing a user's view but marketing it. My question is how can I remove these tweets and just have the user view tweets for sentiment analysis.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Like if someone gone through the liposuction treatment: his tweet will be like: the treatment has good results. Or there is no advantage of treatments but if a clinic is doing some marketing type thing about the treatmen that tweet will be like now liposuction is easy and less expensive and so on.

Comment: It'd be helpful to show some (e.g. 5 to 20) examples of good tweets (that you want to keep) and bad tweets (that you want to filter away).

Comment: Interesting, well the first way that comes to mind is to look for keywords and if a particular tweet has keywords like "sale", "buy now", "fast and easy", etc. then its a marketing tweet. But if it contains numbers then it can be considered a good tweet.

Comment: okay do you know any way of removing those tweets?

Comment: "removing those tweets" I'm not sure what you meen by that because you cant delete another persons tweets. If you are instead writing an application that collects tweets, you can for example; collect all of them, then go though each tweet and scan it for the keywords. If the tweet good then add to an array otherwise don't add it.

Comment: okay, thanks I will see about it.